# Next.js Error: 500 (Internal Server Error) for Email Submission Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make an email submission form using Next.js and Resend. I want the form to take inputs for name, email, and message and send them to the email I directed into the route.js code. There's probably an easier way to do this, but this is where I got with the documentation I followed.

I followed a few documents from Resend and other sources and I could not figure out what was wrong with my code. I'm also new to APIs as I haven't used them that much.

This is the error code

(console)

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/route 500 (Internal Server Error) | Contact.jsx:21
```

(terminal)

```
Error: TypeError: (0 , _components_EmailTemplate__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.EmailTemplate) is not a function at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/route.js:26:96)
```

This is the source code

Contact.jsx

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, React } from "react";
import { Resend } from "resend";
import { AiOutlineMail } from "react-icons/ai";
import { BsFillPersonLinesFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { FaGithub, FaLinkedinIn } from "react-icons/fa";
import { HiOutlineChevronDoubleUp } from "react-icons/hi";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

function Contact() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
  });

  const sendEmail = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/api/route", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
    
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setData({
            name: "",
            email: "",
            message: "",
          });
          toast.success(`Hey ${data.name}, your message was sent successfully!`);
        } else {
          const responseData = await response.json(); // Attempt to parse the response JSON
          console.error("Email sending failed:", responseData);
          toast.error("Failed to send email. Please try again later.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending email:", error);
        toast.error("An error occurred while sending the email.");
      }
    };
  
  return (
    {/* Contact Html */}
  )
}
export default Contact;
```

In the html for the component, this is my the code for my form:

```
<form onSubmit={sendEmail}>
  <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-4 w-full py-2">
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <input
        className="border-2 rounded-lg p-3 flex border-gray-300 text-gray-600"
        type="text"
        required="true"
        placeholder="NAME"
        name="name"
        value={data.name}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setData({ ...data, name: e.target.value })
        }
        />
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <input
          className="border-2 rounded-lg p-3 flex border-gray-300 text-gray-600"
          type="email"
          required="true"
          placeholder="EMAIL"
          name="email"
          value={data.email}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setData({ ...data, email: e.target.value })
          }
          />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="flex flex-col py-4">
      <textarea
        className="border-2 rounded-lg p-3 border-gray-300 text-gray-600"
        rows="8"
        required="true"
        placeholder="MESSAGE"
        name="message"
        value={data.message}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setData({ ...data, message: e.target.value })
         }
        ></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" className="w-full p-4 mt-4 gradient-1-bg">
      Send
    </button>
  </form>
```

route.js

```
import { EmailTemplate } from "../../components/EmailTemplate";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { Resend } from "resend";

const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_API_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const { email, name, message } = req.body;

      const data = await resend.emails.send({
        from: 'Moe <onboarding@mohue.org>',
        to: ['inbox@mohue.org'],
        subject: 'Hello world',
        react: EmailTemplate({ firstName: name, message }),
      });
      
      console.log('Email sending response:', data);
      
      if (data.status === 'success') {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Email Successfully Sent!" });
      } else {
        console.error('Email sending failed:', data);
        res.status(500).json(data);
      }
      
    } else {
      res.status(405).end();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
}
```

EmailTemplate.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const EmailTemplate = ({ firstName, message }) => (
  <div>
    <p>Hello {firstName},</p>
    <p>You received the following message:</p>
    <p>{message}</p>
  </div>
);

export default EmailTemplate;
```

The code is probably all sorts of messed up, so I apologize in advanced for any messiness.

Comment: maybe you forget to import EmailTemplate from './EmailTemplate.jsx';

Comment: I didn't include the imports in the question, I'll edit that now

Comment: change 
import { EmailTemplate } from "../../components/EmailTemplate"; 
to :
import EmailTemplate  from "../../components/EmailTemplate";